# Compiling PHP 7.2 with OpenSSL

Tags: php, compilation, openssl, php-7.2

I am trying to compile `PHP 7.2.5` on a RedHat operation system. I already compiled `OpenSSL 1.1.0h` on my own in a directory of my own `/home/user/openssl-1.1`. These are the lines how I compiled `OpenSSL`

```
TARGET_DIR=/home/usr/openssl-1.1
# ...
./config no-shared --prefix=${TARGET_DIR} --openssldir=${TARGET_DIR}/conf
make INSTALL_PREFIX=${TARGET_DIR}
make install
```

Now, I want to compile `PHP 7.2.5` together with the compiled OpenSSL version. I do it with these lines:

```
PHP_PREFIX=/home/user/php-7.2
export OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/user/openssl-1.1/include/openssl
# ...
./buildconf --force
./configure --prefix="$PHP_PREFIX" \
        --enable-sockets \
        --enable-embed \
        --enable-com-dotnet \
        --enable-ctype \
        --with-curl \
        --enable-mbstring=static \
        --with-gd \
        --enable-soap \
        --enable-pdo=static \
        --with-mp \
        --with-curl=static \
        --with-openssl=static \
        --with-openssl-dir="/home/user/openssl-1.1"
```

But at some point, I get this error message:

```
configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>
```

This file `evp.h` exists in the directory `/home/user/openssl-1.1/include/openssl`.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for **this** problem: One has to change the two parameter `--with-openssl` and `--with-libdir` to something like this:

```
./buildconf --force
./configure --prefix="$PHP_PREFIX" \
# ...
    --with-openssl=/home/user/openssl-1.1 \
    --with-libdir=lib64
```

As fas as I know, no other environment variables are needed here.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested with PHP 7.2 and 7.4

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you installed software in a non-standard prefix, point it to pkgconfig directory of OpenSSL.

Procedure:

1. Install OpenSSL

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1i.tar.gz
tar xzf /root/tmp/openssl/openssl-1.1.1i.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.1i
./Configure --prefix=/opt/openssl-1.1.1i/bin -fPIC -shared linux-x86_64
make -j 8 
make install
```

2. Export the variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH to point to pkgconfig directory

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/openssl-1.1.1i/bin/lib/pkgconfig
```

3. Compile and install PHP.

```
tar xzf php-7.4.13.tar.gz
cd  php-7.4.13

./configure --prefix=/opt/php-7.4.13 --with-curl --enable-exif \
 --with-mhash --enable-mbstring --with-mysqli --enable-mysqlnd \
--with-zlib --with-bz2 --enable-fpm --with-pear -enable-gd\
--with-apxs2=/opt/httpd-2.4.46/bin/apxs - --with-webp \
 --with-jpeg --with-xpm --with-freetype --enable-intl \
--disable-ipv6 --with-pgsql --without-sqlite3 --without-pdo-sqlite \
 --disable-cgi --enable-soap --without-imap --without-imap-ssl \
--with-openssl=/opt/openssl-1.1.1i/bin \
--with-openssl-dir=/opt/openssl-1.1.1i/bin

make -j 8 
make install
```

4. Test the OpenSSL Version

```
/opt/php-7.4.13/bin/php -i | grep -i openssl


OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020
Openssl default config => /opt/openssl-1.1.1i/bin/ssl/openssl.cnf
```